# Update sql query and table contents using radion button and php

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, button

I am newbie.

How can i change the contents of the table using radio buttons and php. **WITHOUT REFRESHING THE PAGE.**

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="page" value="all"> All<br>
<input type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="page" value="old"> Old<br>
<input type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="page" value="new"> New>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$page = null;
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    $page = $_POST['page'];
}
switch($page){
    case 'all': 
    // SQL QUERY
    break;
case 'new': 
    // SQL QUERY
    break;
case 'old': 
    // SQL QUERY
    break;

}
?>
```

The problem is the page will refresh, and the selected radio button will become unselected.

Comment: use ajax to submit the form

Comment: Use jQuery. It simplifies everything.

Comment: show your ajax and jquery code.

Comment: Start here http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Comment: you can add php codition on radio button html also..

Comment: I need an answer, i DON'T want to study ajax. -_-

Comment: Why don't you just pay someone then? Why should people here spend their time working for you for free? Do you have a 401k?

Comment: You need answer and you don't want to study ajax ! Ok go to [HireDeveloperByPaid](https://www.freelancer.com) and find someone to help your problem by paying ....

Comment: I only want to know the code snippet, not just i will need to learn from the whole ajax. the SNIPPET only.

Answer (score 0):

change your form to,

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="yourphppage.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="page" value="all"> All<br>
<input type="radio" name="page" value="old"> Old<br>
<input type="radio" name="page" value="new"> New>
</form>
```

load jquery script in the page. after loading use the following code,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="page"]').on('change',function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#myform').attr('action');
                type: "POST",
                data: {page: $('input[name="page"]').val()},
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

i didnt ran it, but i am pretty sure it will be the solution to your problem. let me know if u face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had used given blow code for resolving this type of problem :-

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="page" value="all"> All<br>
<input type="radio" name="page" value="old"> Old<br>
<input type="radio" name="page" value="new"> New
</form>
 <div id="responsecontainer"></div>
<script>
$(function(){`$(function(){
$("input[name='page']").change(function() {
var form = this.form;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action.php",
data: $(form).serialize(),
 success: function(response){
 $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```